# Как убить процесс запущенный через subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, subprocess

Пишу программу которая запускает и останавливает скрипт Python через другой скрипт Python по просьбе пользователя. И написал следующий код:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import check_output
import psutil

def Start():
    Text = input("Введите 'Старт' или 'Стоп': ")

    if Text == "Старт":
        proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'Script.py'])
        
    elif Text == "Стоп":
        proc.kill()

while True:
    Start()
```

Но мне выводит ошибку когда пытаюсь остановить процесс.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\main.py", line 39, in Start
    killprocess("BOT_VK_ExCase3D.py")

  File "C:\Users\User\main.py", line 23, in killprocess
    pid = get_pid(name)

  File "C:\Users\User\main.py", line 20, in get_pid
    return map(int, check_output(["pidof", name]).split())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] ═"непонятные символы"
```

Вопрос: Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc = None

def Start():
    global proc
    Text = input("Введите 'Старт' или 'Стоп': ")

    if Text == "Старт":
        proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'Script.py'])
        
    elif Text == "Стоп" and proc:
        proc.kill()
```

Comment: поставьте галочку слева, если вопрос решен.

Comment: Если мы пишем "Старт", а потом "Стоп", то процесс не закроется и выдаст ошибку: идентификатор proc не определён, так как это всё находиться в функции, а программа повторяется снова и снова и мы снова и снова вызываем функцию. (я просто не весь код написал: снизу надо добавить Start() и всю программу запихать в цикл)

Comment: @ValleraProgrammist это уже другой вопрос ;)

Comment: ну дак поможете?

Comment: Может можно ещё один скрипт Python делать, который это всё будет обрабатывать? Я буду доволен любым способом

Comment: @ValleraProgrammist завтра напишу

Comment: Спасибо, сам бы не догадался)